# Simplify draw on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

[This is my code.](https://jsfiddle.net/Crocsx/dh0y77u0/)

Forget about some stuff outside the function (is just to make it clear on fiddle, it's a part of a bigger code.

Basically I have this part :

```
var drawDataSet = function (dataset) {
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    var angle = (Math.PI) / (dataset.data.length / 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
        var height = ((canvas.height / 2 * dataset.data[i]) / 100);
        context.lineTo(Math.cos(angle * i) * height, -Math.sin(angle * i) * height);
    }
    var height = ((canvas.height / 2 * dataset.data[0]) / 100);
    context.lineTo(height, 0);
    context.closePath();
    context.strokeStyle = dataset.strokeColor;
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = dataset.fillColor;
    context.fill();
    context.fillStyle = dataset.pointfillColor;
    context.fillStyle = dataset.pointStrokeColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
        var height = ((canvas.height / 2 * dataset.data[i]) / 100);
        drawPoint(Math.cos(angle * i) * height, -Math.sin(angle * i) * height, 3);
    }
    context.restore();
}

drawPoint = function (x,y,w) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, w, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
}
```

I would like to know if there is an easier and better way to draw the same thing.

Actually I do the same exact loop 2 times at different position. This is because if I draw all in the same loop, everything breaks because the `closePath` closes all the paths. If I remove the `closePath`, it only breaks the fill and stroke.

Is it possible to put the `drawPoint` and the `drawLine` in the same loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Technically, Yes...**

You can combine your draws in a single loop

You could draw your lines and points at the same time with a single loop by saving & restoring the context when you draw your current line and your current point. And some compositing must be done to keep your lines draw behind your points.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

var points=[ {x:25,y:50},{x:100,y:25},{x:150,y:85},{x:125,y:100},{x:25,y:50}  ];
var lastX,lastY;

lastX=points[0].x;
lastY=points[0].y;

for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
  var p=points[i];
  drawLine(lastX,lastY,p.x,p.y,'green');
  drawPoint(p.x,p.y,3,'blue','red');
  lastX=p.x;
  lastY=p.y;
}


function drawLine(x0,y0,x1,y1,stroke){
  context.save();
  context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
  context.lineWidth=2;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x0,y0);
  context.lineTo(x1,y1);
  context.strokeStyle=stroke;
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function drawPoint(x,y,w,fill,stroke) {
  context.save();
  context.lineWidth=2;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, w, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.strokeStyle=stroke;
  context.fillStyle=fill;
  context.stroke();
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Alternatively, you could draw your lines & points in a single `beginPath` if you are willing to have just 1 color for both strokeStyle fillStyle.

**But...performance is better if you draw the lines & points in separate loops**

Saving & restoring the context is modestly expensive.

Since you are constantly saving & restoring, you get a in loss of performance versus doing 2 loops without save & restore.